# Blog architecture design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, architecture, blogs

I'm teaching myself rails, and want to build a blog similar to tumblr. It will have a couple different post types, such as written text, photo posts, audio posts, and video posts.

My initial thought was to have different models for each type of post, since there will be different rules for each type of post. However, I'm still learning and don't know what I don't know, so maybe there is a better way to go about things (maybe only one model for posts, and a table for post types?).

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Both the answers below sound reasonable to me. The only thing I'd want to float out there to keep in mind is a lot of the rails "magic" between db and models has to do with following conventions (convention over configuration) and if you try to slap 2 models on the same table you'll possibly have issues getting things working.

Comment: I was sitting and thinking about making a simple blogging platform and how to design it. I opened SO and there's your question at the top! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a good relational database and object oriented design would be to have one main post model, which will probably share mostly same attributes and behaviors with all the types of posts. This could even act as your "text" type posts.

This could also simplify relationships with the posts also (eg. "users has many posts" vs "users has many text posts and/or video posts and/or etc").

Then have a sort of "attachments" join table, which determines the type of attachment (so you can have multiple attachments per post):

```
CREATE TABLE attachments (post_id, media_type, media_id)
```

Then have a table and model for each type for specific behaviors and handlers for the media types.

```
CREATE TABLE audios (id, transcription, storage);
CREATE TABLE videos (id, location, format, storage);
```

This will probably require some sort of polymorphic relationship, though, which could be a debatable DB design... you'll need views and triggers to query easily and maintain integrity...  but Rails handles it quite well.

The post model would have

```
has_many :attachments
```

and attachments would have

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :media, :polymorphic => true
```

and each of the media model would have

```
has_one :attachment, :as => :media
```

then you can access your media via

```
post.attachments[0].media
```

You can skip the attachments table and merge the attributes with the posts table if you only need one type of media per post

Sorry i keep editing, i keep thinking of more things to to say :)

Comment: Hi Janechii, thanks for the answer, and no worries about the editing :) I'm having some difficulty figuring out exactly how your answer would work... Would I have one table for Posts with basic shared characteristics such as user_id and title, then have individual models for each of the types of media (audio, video etc...), then have an attachment table PostMedia where it would have one post and one media type?

Comment: i've edited the answer.. it's a bit complicated, but will allow a lot of flexibility, i think. You can read up more on polymorphic relationship on any rails tutorials.

Comment: Thanks janechii, if I only wanted one type of media per post, how would I go about doing that? From my research on polymorphic relationships, they are primarily for child attributes (such as comments on multiple models), not parent attributes (Posts have multiple media). Or would I just treat the Post table like a child attribute?

Comment: Sorry to get back so late. You can just define the polymorphic in the post model instead of the attachemnts that i mentioned. That will give you one media per post. Technically a post would be a "child" of one of the media types, so it should be an accurate representation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of options that could work.

First, you could just make one Model with columns for `text_content`, `video_link`, `photo_link`, etc.

Then in your view, you could render the post's view to the user (probably using a partial) with a different look depending on which attributes have values.

A second option would be to make a smaller `Post` table that just had key information and use a series of 'has_one' relationships to the other items.

The only advantage I see to the second option is that your DB table would be smaller since you don't have to represent the null cells over and over.  Unless your worried about some huge scaling issues, I'd go with the 1st option though.

Comment: Thanks for answering Brian! There are some other unique aspects to the various posts that might make a difference. For example, a text post could have a large amount of text, while a photo post would have a limited sized caption. Can you elaborate a bit more on your second option?